# Add percentage to value (python)

Tags: python, addition, percentage

I have code writing data to 3 different files. I need to add sales tax to the price output of f3 that will change the price value. what would be the cleanest way to do this?

Edit: price structure is (00.00)

```
 # write compiled product to buylist.txt
def write_output(self):
    with open(self.outputfile, 'w') as f, open(self.outputfile2, 'w') as f2, open(self.outputfile3, 'w') as f3:
        for item in self.buylist:
            f.write(str(item['status']) + " " + str(item['item']) + " " + str(item['quantity'])+ " " + str(item['price']) + "\n")
            f2.write(str(item['item']) + " " + str(item['quantity']) + "\n")
            f3.write(str(item['item']) + " " + str(item['quantity'])+ " " + str(item['price']) + "\n")
    f.close(), f2.close(), f3.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code, Although this is not a very good way to ask a question since you have not mentioned data type of price or given an example.

You will only need to edit the `f3.write` line

```
salesTax = 18
f3.write(str(item['item']) + " " + str(item['quantity'])+ " " + str(int(item['price']) * (1 + (salesTax/100))) + "\n")
```

Comment: You are right. Data type/ price structure is standard 2-place decimal (00.00)

Comment: Thank you! It works great. as a note, there is one too many parentheses.